# What does it mean when it says that my debugger is detached?

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, xdebug-3

I recently found *Xdebug* for PHP and decided to try it out. It works well for debugging in the console, but for some reason, it does not work at all from the browser.

I navigate to `localhost` with the debugger enabled in my IDE (green bug icon in PhpStorm), while having made sure to enable the step debugger in *Xdebug*, yet nothing happens. All I know is that the output of `xdebug_info();` tells me that the **debugger** is **detached**, which does not make any sense.

I tried to search the Internet but could not find any mention of what this status actually means. I appreciate any help that could point me in the right direction, as I am currently stuck without anything to go by.

*/etc/php/8.1/mods-available/xdebug.ini*

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

*Xdebug helper* (Firefox extension)

[image]

Output from `xdebug_info();`

[image]

Log file

```
[1079] Log opened at 2023-09-30 23:31:06.561542
[1079] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' not found, falling back to 'XDEBUG_SESSION'
[1079] [Config] INFO: No shared secret: Activating
[1079] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9003.
[1079] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 127.0.0.1:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
[1079] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.1.12-1ubuntu4.3" protocol_version="1.0" appid="1079" idekey="XDEBUG_ECLIPSE"><engine version="3.2.0"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2022 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[1079] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 1 -- KHN0cmluZykoaW5pX2dldCgneGRlYnVnLmNvdmVyYWdlX2VuYWJsZScpLic7Jy5pbmlfZ2V0KCd4ZGVidWcucHJvZmlsZXJfZW5hYmxlJykuJzsnLmluaV9nZXQoJ3hkZWJ1Zy5yZW1vdGVfYXV0b3N0YXJ0JykuJzsnLmluaV9nZXQoJ3hkZWJ1Zy5yZW1vdGVfY29ubmVjdF9iYWNrJykuJzsnLmluaV9nZXQoJ3hkZWJ1Zy5yZW1vdGVfbW9kZScpKQ==
[1079] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="1"><property type="string" size="635" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[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]]></property></response>

[1079] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 2 -n show_hidden -v 1
[1079] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

[1079] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 3 -n max_depth -v 1
[1079] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

[1079] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 4 -n max_children -v 100
[1079] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

[1079] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 5 -n extended_properties -v 1
[1079] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="5" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>

[1079] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 6 -n notify_ok -v 1
[1079] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="6" feature="notify_ok" success="1"></response>

[1079] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 7 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
[1079] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="7" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[1079] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 8 -n breakpoint_include_return_value -v 1
[1079] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="8" feature="breakpoint_include_return_value" success="1"></response>

[1079] [Step Debug] <- stdout -i 9 -c 1
[1079] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stdout" transaction_id="9" success="1"></response>

[1079] [Step Debug] <- status -i 10
[1079] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="10" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>

[1079] [Step Debug] <- step_into -i 11
[1079] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="11" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///var/www/html/index.php" lineno="2"></xdebug:message></response>

[1079] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 12 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1BIUF9JREVfQ09ORklHJ10p
[1079] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="12"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[0]]></property></response>

[1079] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 13 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9OQU1FJ10p
[1079] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="13"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[1]]></property></response>

[1079] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 14 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9OQU1FJ10p
[1079] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="14"><property type="string" size="1" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[Xw==]]></property></response>

[1079] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 15 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9QT1JUJ10p
[1079] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="15"><property type="string" size="2" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[ODA=]]></property></response>

[1079] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 16 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1JFUVVFU1RfVVJJJ10p
[1079] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="16"><property type="string" size="1" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[Lw==]]></property></response>

[1079] [Step Debug] <- detach -i 17
[1079] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="detach" transaction_id="17" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[1079] Log closed at 2023-09-30 23:31:06.589876
```

Debug settings

[image]

File being debugged

[image]

Servers

[image]

Comment: Enable logging (`xdebug.log`), restart webserver (make sure that setting is used), try to debug in the same way .. then check the log -- it will give you some ideas.

Comment: This is not precise .. but anyway: this should be when Xdebug has established the connection with the IDE just fine .. but the IDE has no valid breakpoints (or other conditions) where to stop.. so the debug client (PhpStorm in this case) is detached. https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug#xdebug_is_debugger_active

Comment: Another "detach" is when you are debugging a scrip (certain part of it) and you are done with the debugging but still want to let the script to execute to the end. In this case you can use Detach button in PhpStorm and the PHP will execute the script ignoring any possible breakpoints.

Comment: I have added the log file to my question. I will try to make sense of it, but perhaps someone else can spot something interesting in the meantime.

Comment: As for the breakpoints in my IDE, I have tried to add them through the area that shows the line number, which highlights the marked line in red, and I even tried the _Break at first line in PHP scripts_ option under Settings -> PHP -> Debug

Comment: As far as I can see there are no breakpoints set by the IDE. Maybe you do not have any? Or the IDE ignores this connection (different domain name etc). What kind of file are you trying to debug? etc. Try the simplest possible, something like `<?php $a = 1; $b = 3; $c = $a + $b; echo $c;` with each instruction on own line. Set breakpoint at the first `$a = ` line and see how it will go...

Comment: I definitely have break points, and the domain is `127.0.0.1`. The file I am currently debugging is a simple one, much like the one you suggested.

Comment: 1) Show your PhpStorm Xdebug setting -- maybe something is on or off there that should not be; 2) show your test file with breakpoints. Maybe it will show something (very unlikely though if it's a simple file); 3) Show your "PHP | Servers" entry -- maybe something is off there.

Comment: 4) Try deleting the "PHP | Servers" entry that you have for this website (all of them if you have more than one). then try to debug and the IDE should help creating you the new one next time. Other than that -- make some screencast with your debug setup and process  -- it may show nuances that are ignored/not "visible" with static screenshots...

Comment: I removed the server entry and let PhpStorm recreate it. Now it works as expected, although I have no idea as to why. The host is nothing more than an underscore.

Comment: I got all excited and jumped back to debugging my original code. I wish to thank you for your help. It seems unlikely that I would have figured this out on my own. Thank you very much!

Comment: *"The host is nothing more than an underscore."* Not sure what you mean here. As per your screenshot the host name was `localhost`. And you have "Ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations" option enabled... If the host name was different before and now .. then yes, the IDE would ignore such incoming debug connections. If that screenshot of "PHP | Servers" entry is the original one then compare it to what you have right now. if it's new -- well, see if you can remember what you have had there before.

Comment: The image shows the old configuration. Only difference is that the host became an underscore. Otherwise, everything is the same.

Comment: OK. What webserver/environment is that? XAMPP or alike? Must be the change (or the way you/the tool have configured) in the web server config. Because `_` (underscore) is what PHP returns for `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` .. which is used by PhpStorm to decide what "PHP | Servers" entry to use...

Comment: I am running Nginx on Ubuntu with the default configuration. Only thing I changed was to enable PHP-FPM.